# Proving sets implication using the method of contradiction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose S and T are sets. Consider the following implication:
If $A∩B=∅$ and $A ∪B = B$, then $A = ∅$.

Prove the given implication by contradiction.

So I have started by coming up with the negation:
$A∩B=∅$ and $A ∪B = B$ and  $A ≠∅$.

I tried:

> $A∩B= A∩(A ∪B)$
>
> $A∩B= (A∩A) ∪ (A∩B)$
>
> $A∩B= A ∪ (A∩B)$
>
> $A∩B= A ∪ ∅$
>
> $A∩B= A$

Is this a contradiction? Or am I doing something wrong? I have no clue what to do with this. Any help/ hints would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of contradiction, assume that $A \neq \emptyset$, along with $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cup B = B$. This implies that there exists an element in $A$, i.e. $\exists x \in A$.

Now, $A \cap B = \emptyset$ implies that $x \notin B$. Why does this contradict $A \cup B = B$?

Comment: thanks a lot man! If $x∈A∪B,$ then $(x∈A) ∨ (x∈B)$. Since $x∉B$, $x$ must be $∈A$. This means $A∪B=A$. But our assumption is $A∪B=B$. This is a contradiction. Our assumption is wrong and thus, the original statement holds. Is that right?

Comment: Not quite... $A \cup B$ does not necessarily have to be $A$. This is true only if $B \subseteq A$, which we don't know. You can show that $A \cup B \neq B$ by considering whether $x$ is in both sets.

Comment: ohh... how about this? If $x∈A∪B,$ then $(x∈A) ∨ (x∈B)$. Since $x∉B$, then $A∪B≠B$. But our assumption is $A∪B=B$. This is a contradiction. Our assumption is wrong and thus, the original statement holds.

Comment: Exactly! Since $x \in A \subseteq A \cup B$, and $x \notin B$, $A \cup B \neq B$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

$A \cup B=B$ implies $A \subset B$,  and $A\subset B$ implies $A \cap B=A$.

Therefore  $A=A \cap B=\emptyset$.